# Update binding component

Tags: jsf

I have a `panelGrid`:

```
 <h:form id="form_add">
         <h:panelGrid columns="4" id="binding" binding="#{myBean.pnGrid}">
         </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

and the AJAX that updates this panelGrid is:

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{leftprocess.onChange}" update=":form_main:form_left:form_add"/>
```

but the AJAX doesn't update the `panelGrid`. I searched on the internet but I can not resolve the issue.

Comment: The client ID in the `update` attribute suggests that you're nesting forms in each other. Is this true?

Comment: yes, i am nesting forms in each other :)